# Required resource upon deploy not matching the instructions in the pom

Tags: dependencies, osgi, apache-felix

I am running through the book "[OSGi and Apache Felix 3.0](http://www.packtpub.com/osgi-and-apache-felix-30-beginners-guide/book)" and have hit a problem where a bundle I am deploying insists that it has a dependency on the wrong version of another bundle. For anyone who has worked through these examples before, I am just at the end of chapter 10 - implementing logging functionality in the Bookshelf Service Bundle.

Basically the problem is as follows:

I have a bundle called "Bookshelf Service" to which I have just added some sweet new logging functionality. This new functionality puts it at version 1.10.0

I have another bundle called "Bookshelf Service Gogo commands" which is a command-line interface to functionality in "Bookshelf Service". It is at version 1.9.0.

What is puzzling is that when I deploy the "Bookshelf Service Gogo commands" bundle, it installs as follows:

```
deploy -s "Bookshelf Service Gogo commands"

Target resource(s):
-------------------
Bookshelf Service Gogo commands (1.9.0)

Required resource(s):
---------------------
Bookshelf Service (1.7.0)
```

Which of course is the wrong version of the 'Bookshelf Service' Bundle. I want to be using version 1.10.0.

If I update, or force the framework to use version 1.10.0, then the functionality that "Bookshelf Service Gogo commands" offers ceases to be available. It is refusing to work with the newest version of 'Bookshelf Service'.

According to the pom.xml file though, the dependency is indeed for the 1.10.0 version of 'Bookshelf Service'. The POM for "Bookshelf Service Gogo commands" is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packtpub.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-service-tui</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0</version>

  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Bookshelf Service Gogo commands</name>
  <description>The text user-interface</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.packtpub.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version> 
            <type>bundle</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Category>sample</Bundle-Category>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.tui
                        </Export-Package>
            <!--        <Bundle-Activator>
                            com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.tui.activator.BookshelfTuiActivator
                        </Bundle-Activator>
                        <Private-Package>
                            com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.tui.activator
                     </Private-Package>
            -->
                    </instructions>

                    <remoteOBR>repo-rel</remoteOBR>
                    <prefixUrl>file:/home/awalker/sandbox_workspace/releases</prefixUrl>
                    <ignoreLock>true</ignoreLock>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ipojo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ipojo-bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <metadata>src/main/ipojo/meta.xml</metadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- releases repo -->
        <repository>
            <id>repo-rel</id>
            <url>file:/home/awalker/sandbox_workspace/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

So I don't understand why it only wants to work with 1.7.0.

It is also worth mentioning that both of these bundles are taking advantage of iPOJO, so they do have meta.xml files. I don't think the problem is there however, because I have been comparing my code to the downloadable sample code for the book examples, and everything seems to match.

Any ideas about what is going wrong, or where to look for the source of this problem?

---

EDIT:

As per request, the generated manifests.

Bookshelf Service 1.7.0:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api;uses:="com.pa
 cktpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api",com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.se
 rvice.impl;uses:="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api,com.pack
 tpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api,org.osgi.framework"
Built-By: awalker
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Category: sample
Bundle-Name: Bookshelf Service
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Bundle-Version: 1.7.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1305055936964
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.impl.activator.
 BookshelfServiceImplActivator
Bundle-Description: This Bookshelf Service
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-service
Import-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api,com.packtpu
 b.felix.bookshelf.service.api,com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.im
 pl,org.osgi.framework;version="1.5"
```

Bookshelf Service version 1.10.0

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api;uses:="com.pa
 cktpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api",com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.se
 rvice.impl;uses:="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api,com.pack
 tpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api,com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.log.api
 "
iPOJO-Components: component { $immediate="true" $name="BookshelfServic
 eImpl" $classname="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.impl.Bookshel
 fServiceImpl" provides { }manipulation { field { $name="sessionId" $t
 ype="java.lang.String" }field { $name="inventory" $type="com.packtpub
 .felix.bookshelf.inventory.api.BookInventory" }field { $name="logger"
  $type="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.log.api.BookshelfLogHelper" }met
 hod { $name="$init" }method { $name="getLogger" $return="com.packtpub
 .felix.bookshelf.log.api.BookshelfLogHelper" }method { $name="lookupB
 ookInventory" $return="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api.Boo
 kInventory" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,char[]}" $name="l
 ogin" $return="java.lang.String" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.Str
 ing}" $name="logout" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String}" $name=
 "sessionIsValid" $return="boolean" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.S
 tring}" $name="checkSession" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,
 java.lang.String}" $name="getBook" $return="com.packtpub.felix.booksh
 elf.inventory.api.Book" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,java.
 lang.String}" $name="getBookForEdit" $return="com.packtpub.felix.book
 shelf.inventory.api.MutableBook" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.Str
 ing,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Stri
 ng,int}" $name="addBook" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,java
 .lang.String,java.lang.String}" $name="modifyBookCategory" }method { 
 $arguments="{java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int}" $name="modifyBoo
 kRating" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String}" $name="getCategori
 es" $return="java.util.Set" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,j
 ava.lang.String}" $name="removeBook" }method { $arguments="{java.lang
 .String,java.lang.String}" $name="searchBooksByAuthor" $return="java.
 util.Set" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,java.lang.String}" 
 $name="searchBooksByCategory" $return="java.util.Set" }method { $argu
 ments="{java.lang.String,java.lang.String}" $name="searchBooksByTitle
 " $return="java.util.Set" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,int
 ,int}" $name="searchBooksByRating" $return="java.util.Set" }interface
  { $name="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api.BookshelfService" 
 }}requires { $field="inventory" }requires { $field="logger" }}instanc
 e { $component="BookshelfServiceImpl" $name="bookshelf.service.impl" 
 }
Built-By: awalker
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Category: sample
Bundle-Name: Bookshelf Service
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin & iPOJO  1.6.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Bundle-Version: 1.10.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1305656960793
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: This Bookshelf Service
Import-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api, org.osgi.s
 ervice.log;version=1.3, com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.impl, co
 m.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api, org.apache.felix.ipojo.archit
 ecture;version= 1.6.0, com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.log.api, org.apac
 he.felix.ipojo;version= 1.6.0, org.osgi.service.cm;version=1.2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-service
```

Bookshelf Service Gogo commands 1.9.0

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.tui;uses:="com.pa
 cktpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api,com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.ser
 vice.api,org.apache.felix.service.command"
iPOJO-Components: instance { $component="BookshelfServiceProxy" $name=
 "bookshelf.service.tui" }component { $name="BookshelfServiceProxy" $c
 lassname="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.tui.BookshelfServicePr
 oxyImpl" $public="true" provides { property { $field="gogoScope" $nam
 e="osgi.command.scope" $value="book" }property { $field="gogoFunction
 s" $name="osgi.command.function" $value="[add,search]" }}manipulation
  { field { $name="bookshelf" $type="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.serv
 ice.api.BookshelfService" }field { $name="gogoScope" $type="java.lang
 .String" }field { $name="gogoFunctions" $type="java.lang.String[]" }m
 ethod { $name="$init" }method { $name="lookupService" $return="com.pa
 cktpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api.BookshelfService" }method { $argum
 ents="{java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.S
 tring,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int}" $name="add" $return="ja
 va.lang.String" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,java.lang.Str
 ing,java.lang.String,java.lang.String}" $name="search" $return="java.
 util.Set" }method { $arguments="{java.lang.String,java.lang.String,ja
 va.lang.String,int,int}" $name="search" $return="java.util.Set" }meth
 od { $arguments="{java.lang.String,com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.servi
 ce.api.BookshelfService,java.util.Set}" $name="getBooks" $return="jav
 a.util.Set" }interface { $name="com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.
 tui.BookshelfServiceProxy" }}requires { $field="bookshelf" }}
Built-By: awalker
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Category: sample
Bundle-Name: Bookshelf Service Gogo commands
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin & iPOJO  1.6.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Bundle-Version: 1.9.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1305650360964
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: The text user-interface
Import-Package: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api, org.osgi.s
 ervice.log;version=1.3, org.apache.felix.service.command;status=provi
 sional;version=0.8, com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.service.api, org.apa
 che.felix.ipojo.architecture;version= 1.6.0, org.apache.felix.ipojo;v
 ersion= 1.6.0, org.osgi.service.cm;version=1.2, com.packtpub.felix.bo
 okshelf.service.tui
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-service-tui
```

Comment: I have a feeling what is going on (to confirm it, try typing `refresh` in the console, I'll provide the detailed answer later), but could you please include the generated manifests of the three bundles you're talking about?

Comment: I typed refresh, and I got the 'Welcome to Apache Felix' message - then once I used the command lb to view changes, I got an error stating an IllegalStateException with an Invalid BundleContext.

Comment: Judging from the manifests, it looks a little more mundane than I thought it would be: my best guess is that your bundles have some service dependencies that aren't met, e.g. the log service of config admin. Otherwise, I'm at a loss, as I haven't read the book, and it's hard to judge exactly what's going on on your system through an exchange of comments.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is years late, but I just ran into almost the same problem, following along the same book. It turned out the issue was that I'd broken the Export-Package commands in the pom.xml for the original Bookshelf Service bundle in going from the 1.7.0 to 1.10.0 versions. Check things carefully - what the 'instance' command says about the problems with the installed bundles that aren't running, what the manifest files say, what's in pom.xml, etc.